# check for equality on slices without order

Tags: go, slice, equality

I am trying to find a solution to check for equality in 2 slices. Unfortanely, the answers I have found require values in the slice to be in the same order. For example, http://play.golang.org/p/yV0q1_u3xR evaluates equality to false.
 I want a solution that lets `[]string{"a","b","c"} == []string{"b","a","c"}` evaluate to `true`.
**MORE EXAMPLES**
`[]string{"a","a","c"} == []string{"c","a","c"}` >>> `false`
`[]string{"z","z","x"} == []string{"x","z","z"}` >>> `true`

Comment: This one should be marked as the concrete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66062073/6093604 (from my point of view) :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution, though perhaps a bit verbose:

```
func sameStringSlice(x, y []string) bool {
    if len(x) != len(y) {
        return false
    }
    // create a map of string -> int
    diff := make(map[string]int, len(x))
    for _, _x := range x {
        // 0 value for int is 0, so just increment a counter for the string
        diff[_x]++
    }
    for _, _y := range y {
        // If the string _y is not in diff bail out early
        if _, ok := diff[_y]; !ok {
            return false
        }
        diff[_y]--
        if diff[_y] == 0 {
            delete(diff, _y)
        }
    }
    return len(diff) == 0
}
```

Try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/06JriIWhXM2)</kbd>

Comment: this is a great answer! just a minor addition, perhaps we can reduce the map access like https://go.dev/play/p/LRHYn22zwkm:
```
        // If the string _y is not in diff bail out early
        current, ok := diff[_y]
        if !ok {
            return false
        }
        if current == 1 {
            delete(diff, _y)
            continue
        }
        diff[_y]--
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`cmp.Diff`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Diff) together with [`cmpopts.SortSlices`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts#SortSlices):

```
less := func(a, b string) bool { return a < b }
equalIgnoreOrder := cmp.Diff(x, y, cmpopts.SortSlices(less)) == ""
```

Here is a full example that runs on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7aggB3H4KWZ):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts"
)

func main() {
    x := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    y := []string{"a", "c", "b"}
    
    less := func(a, b string) bool { return a < b }
    equalIgnoreOrder := cmp.Diff(x, y, cmpopts.SortSlices(less)) == ""
    fmt.Println(equalIgnoreOrder) // prints "true"

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `cmp.Equal` instead of `cmp.Diff`  if you just want a boolean result?

Comment: Caveat Emptor from cmp documentation: >>> [cmp] It is intended to only be used in tests, as performance is not a goal and it may panic if it cannot compare the values. Its propensity towards panicking means that its unsuitable for production environments where a spurious panic may be fatal.

Answer (score 13):

Like [adrianlzt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407722/adrianlzt) wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389509/1475347), an implementation of `assert.ElementsMatch` from [testify](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert) can be used to achieve that. But how about reusing actual testify module instead of copying that code when all you need is a bool result of the comparison? The implementation in testify is intended for tests code and usually takes `testing.T` argument.

It turns out that ElementsMatch can be quite easily used outside of testing code. All it takes is a dummy implementation of an interface with `ErrorF` method:

```go
type dummyt struct{}

func (t dummyt) Errorf(string, ...interface{}) {}

func elementsMatch(listA, listB interface{}) bool {
    return assert.ElementsMatch(dummyt{}, listA, listB)
}
```

Or test it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BgcklcWGrap), which I've adapted from the adrianlzt's example.

Comment: As easy as useful :) thanks:

Answer (score 12):

The other answers have better time complexity `O(N)` vs `(O(N log(N))`, that are in my answer, also my solution will take up more memory if elements in the slices are repeated frequently, but I wanted to add it because I think this is the most straight forward way to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "reflect"
)

func array_sorted_equal(a, b []string) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {return false }

    a_copy := make([]string, len(a))
    b_copy := make([]string, len(b))

    copy(a_copy, a)
    copy(b_copy, b)

    sort.Strings(a_copy)
    sort.Strings(b_copy)

    return reflect.DeepEqual(a_copy, b_copy)
}

func main() {
    a := []string {"a", "a", "c"}
    b := []string {"c", "a", "c"}
    c := []string {"z","z","x"} 
    d := []string {"x","z","z"}


    fmt.Println( array_sorted_equal(a, b))
    fmt.Println( array_sorted_equal(c, d))

}
```

Result:

```
false
true
```

Comment: For me this is the simpler answer (leaving performance out of the table, BTW nobody should care about it unless is part of the spec). Sort both slices and then compare then element by element in a given order (asc or desc..). I was preparing an example in the golang playground like this => https://go.dev/play/p/zg2MH_FhCAO

Comment: I think sometimes people get a bit blinded by big O notation and forgets that map ops are actually really expensive. If benchmarked this solution vs the top one using a map with slices containing 79 elements give this result:
BenchmarkCmpWithSortEqual-12          188334       6895 ns/op
BenchmarkCmpWithSortNotEqual-12       187402       6082 ns/op
BenchmarkCmpWithMapEqual-12            31605      36686 ns/op
BenchmarkCmpWithMapNotEqual-12         32548      36428 ns/op

Answer (score 8):

I would think the easiest way would be to map the elements in each array/slice to their number of occurrences, then compare the maps:

```
func main() {
    x := []string{"a","b","c"}
    y := []string{"c","b","a"}

    xMap := make(map[string]int)
    yMap := make(map[string]int)

    for _, xElem := range x {
        xMap[xElem]++
    }
    for _, yElem := range y {
        yMap[yElem]++
    }

    for xMapKey, xMapVal := range xMap {
        if yMap[xMapKey] != xMapVal {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

You'll need to add some additional due dilligence, like short circuiting if your arrays/slices contain elements of different types or are of different length.

Comment: Good answer @dimitar, I like the approach.  +1 from me.

Comment: This solution is WRONG, it returns true even if the second slice contains strings that are not in the first one, for example `x=[a,b], y=[a,b,c]`. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/oydEKpbseaH

Comment: @Dirbaio, that's absolutely right, which is why my answer notes _You'll need to add some additional due dilligence, like short circuiting if your arrays/slices contain elements of different types or are of different length._

Answer (score 8):

Generalizing the code of [testify ElementsMatch](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/85f2b59c4459e5bf57488796be8c3667cb8246d6/assert/assertions.go#L836), solution to compare any kind of objects (in the example `[]map[string]string`):

https://play.golang.org/p/xUS2ngrUWUl

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't got enough reputation to comment, I have to post yet another answer with a bit better code readability:

```
func AssertSameStringSlice(x, y []string) bool {
    if len(x) != len(y) {
        return false
    }

    itemAppearsTimes := make(map[string]int, len(x))
    for _, i := range x {
        itemAppearsTimes[i]++
    }

    for _, i := range y {
        if _, ok := itemAppearsTimes[i]; !ok {
            return false
        }

        itemAppearsTimes[i]--

        if itemAppearsTimes[i] == 0 {
            delete(itemAppearsTimes, i)
        }
    }

    if len(itemAppearsTimes) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

The logic is the same as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000696/2761550)

Answer (score 0):

I know its been answered but still I would like to add my answer. By following code here [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/assert/assertions.go#L835) we can have something like

```
  func Elementsmatch(listA, listB []string) (string, bool) {
    aLen := len(listA)
    bLen := len(listB)

    if aLen != bLen {
        return fmt.Sprintf("Len of the lists don't match , len listA %v, len listB %v", aLen, bLen), false
    }

    visited := make([]bool, bLen)

    for i := 0; i < aLen; i++ {
        found := false
        element := listA[i]
        for j := 0; j < bLen; j++ {
            if visited[j] {
                continue
            }
            if element == listB[j] {
                visited[j] = true
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            return fmt.Sprintf("element %s appears more times in %s than in %s", element, listA, listB), false
        }
    }
    return "", true
}
```

Now lets talk about performance of this solution compared to map based ones. Well it really depends on the size of the lists which you are comparing, If size of list is large (I would say greater than 20) then map approach is better else this would be sufficent.

Well on [Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/k-MC-b6x6P6) it shows 0s always, but run this on local system and you can see the difference in time taken as size of list increases

So the solution I propose is, adding map based comparision from above [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000696/2906821)

```
func Elementsmatch(listA, listB []string) (string, bool) {
    aLen := len(listA)
    bLen := len(listB)

    if aLen != bLen {
        return fmt.Sprintf("Len of the lists don't match , len listA %v, len listB %v", aLen, bLen), false
    }

    if aLen > 20 {
        return elementsMatchByMap(listA, listB)
    }else{
        return elementsMatchByLoop(listA, listB)
    }

}

func elementsMatchByLoop(listA, listB []string) (string, bool) {
    aLen := len(listA)
    bLen := len(listB)

    visited := make([]bool, bLen)

    for i := 0; i < aLen; i++ {
        found := false
        element := listA[i]
        for j := 0; j < bLen; j++ {
            if visited[j] {
                continue
            }
            if element == listB[j] {
                visited[j] = true
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            return fmt.Sprintf("element %s appears more times in %s than in %s", element, listA, listB), false
        }
    }
    return "", true
}

func elementsMatchByMap(x, y []string) (string, bool) {
    // create a map of string -> int
    diff := make(map[string]int, len(x))
    for _, _x := range x {
        // 0 value for int is 0, so just increment a counter for the string
        diff[_x]++
    }
    for _, _y := range y {
        // If the string _y is not in diff bail out early
        if _, ok := diff[_y]; !ok {
            return fmt.Sprintf(" %v is not present in list b", _y), false
        }
        diff[_y] -= 1
        if diff[_y] == 0 {
            delete(diff, _y)
        }
    }
    if len(diff) == 0 {
        return "", true
    }
    return "", false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Order in slices matters. Make them something different where it doesn't. Then, you can use `reflect`. This implementation also takes in consideration that elements can be repeated.

```
func slicesEqual(want, got []string) bool {
    w := map[string]int{}
    g := map[string]int{}

    for _, v := range want {
        if _, ok := w[v]; !ok {
            w[v] = 1
            continue
        }
        w[v]++
    }

    for _, v := range got {
        if _, ok := g[v]; !ok {
            g[v] = 1
            continue
        }
        g[v]++
    }

    return reflect.DeepEqual(w, g)
}
```